# Showing a set function to be measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and let $\mu:\mathcal A\to [0,+\infty]$ be a finitely additive set function such that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. We want to prove that $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal A$ if for any decreasing sequence $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of sets of $\mathcal A$ with $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\emptyset$, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\mu(A_n) = 0$.

To prove this I must show that $\mu $ is countable subadditive. If I consider any sequence $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of pairwise disjoint sets of $\mathcal A$, then how to construct a decreasing sequence of sets with $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\emptyset$ with the help of the sequence $\{B_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$? If this is done, I believe this problem can be solved. Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you need $A_1$ to have finite measure in your assumption for any decreasing sequence.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=0$ on line $3$?

Comment: @WaysonKong he forgot to take the measure of the set.

Comment: @Xiao He does not need to have $A_1$ with finite measure, the inequality would still hold:

$$\infty = \mu\left(\bigcup_n\mu(A_n)\right) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)$$

Comment: Yes, I realized that the problem is "if" not "iff". What I suggested is actually a weaker condition than the one in the problem.

Comment: No Problem :D @Anupam. What don't you understand in the correct answer given by FisiaiLusia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_n $ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets and let $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n .$ Moreover let $B_n =A\setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k ,$ then $B_{n+1}\subset B_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n =\emptyset . $ Hence if $\mu (A) <\infty$ that $$0=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu (B_n ) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\mu (A) -\sum_{k=1}^n \mu (A_k )\right) =\mu (A) -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu (A_k ) .$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $E = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i$. Analyze the following two cases:

1. $\mu(E)=\infty$.
2. $\mu(E)<\infty$: let $A_k = \cup_{i=k}^{\infty}B_i$, then follow your idea.